# New column for each element in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with many names. I want to create a new column for each of certain names, with 1 if it's the same name, and 0 if not.

Original data:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

I've tried the following:

```
names=['Tom','Sarah','Bob']

def function(x):
    for n in names:
        if (x['Name']==n):
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
        
for n in names:        
    df[n]=df.apply(function,axis=1)
```

This doesn't work because it returns the 'Tom' column for all names:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `get_dummies`

```
out = df.join(df.Name.str.get_dummies()[names])
```

Comment: I actually have multiple conditions (2 columns with a name) but I wanted to simplify it, but it's like this:
 if (x['Name']==n) or (x['Name2']==n)

Answer (score 0):

You needn't the `for` loop in your `function`.

You can use

```py
names = ['Tom','Sarah','Bob']

for n in names:
    df[n] = df['Name'].eq(n).astype(int)
```

Or with numpy broadcasting

```py
df[names] = (df[['Name']].values == names).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually have two columns with names (same names, different order), but I wanted to simplify my question, but it would actually be: if (x['Name']==n) or if (x['Name2']==n): return 1. How would you do that?